# In inline functions, scalar types should be passed by value or reference?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parameter-passing, inline-functions

I know, the question of passing scalars by value vs. by reference has been asked and answered gazillion times before, and I know - in general - they should be passed by value. But what about `inline` functions? And the reason I ask this is I just did some refactoring with Visual Studio 2022, and when I called VS's "Extract Function" command, it extracted the scalar variables like constant reference (e.g. `const int &`).

Does VS know something I don't in relation to `inline` functions, or should I double check and override the code generated by VS?

**Edit #1:**
I also noticed, when pointers were passed as parameters, it didn't use the `inline` keyword. Is it because it knows these functions cannot be inlined? If yes, why?

**Edit #2:**
It also did some other funny things. For example: `(Vehicle *& vehicle_ptr)` It just referenced a pointer. I think it proves that VS does the function extraction using some very simple script.

Comment: It probably just always uses references regardless of the type of the argument

Comment: FWIW, even if you use `inline`, there is no guarantee that the function will be inlined, so pass the parameters as you would normally.

Comment: *"Does VS know something I don't in relation to inline functions"* Unlikely.

Comment: I don't understand how this should affect `inline` functions specifically? Can you elaborate your thoughts, or show some emitted assembly code you have doubts about please?

Comment: I don't understand either. That's why I asked.

Comment: VS's Extract Function is following a cookie cutter script.  It's generically the right thing to do in many cases, but not necessarily in this particular case.  The script could have been made more complicated by checking for this particular case, but maybe it was a Friday and the dev who was working on it was late for happy hour.

Comment: My tip was also that this is the default behavior of VS. The sad part of the story is I noticed just now, after dozens of function extractions. So now, I have to go back and double check all of those `inline` functions. Lesson learned.

Comment: `inline` makes no difference on wether you should pass by value or pass by reference. You can use the information you found in gazillion other places. I suggest https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-conventional because it is rather exhaustive. Note that it does not mention `inline` because it makes no difference

Comment: Thanks for the article! Forked it and I'm gonna read it. Seems useful for a newbie like me. :-)

Comment: IMHO, pass by copy if the object fits into a processor's register.  Otherwise pass by reference or by const reference if the parameter is not changed; regardless of inlining or not.